# Conv3D not working

Tags: android, tensorflow

I built a tensorflow model using `conv3d`, froze it and optimized for inference. When I call the inference in Android (`TensorflowInferenceInterface.run`), I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support
Op 'Conv3D' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
   <no registered kernels>
   [[Node: conv3d/convolution = Conv3D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NDHWC", padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]](images, conv3d/kernel/read)]]
```

I understand, that some ops, including `Conv3D`, are not added to the tensorflow inference library to save space.

So I used `tensorflow/python/tools/print_selective_registration_header.py` script to generate set of ops that are needed to run inference on my graph, put the outputted `ops_to_register.h` to `core/framework` and then built the library using

```
bazel build -c opt --copt="-DSELECTIVE_REGISTRATION" \
--copt="-DSUPPORT_SELECTIVE_REGISTRATION" \
//tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so \
--host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
--crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --cpu=armeabi-v7a
```

Copied the `libtensorflow_inference.so` to my `app/src/main/jniLibs` folder, but the error (`Conv3D` not registered) persists. Do you have an idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like creating `ops_to_register.h` is not enough.
I had to modify the `tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD` file, such that files in `tensorflow/core/kernels/` containing are listed in the `android_extended_ops_group1` or `android_extended_ops_group2` section (and also `.h` files in `android_extended_ops_headers` section.